# Javascript local storage. Get only first 3 elements?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Getting and returning elements from local storage to be displayed is simple:

```
let element = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('element'));
return element.elements
```

Assuming element is the key and elements are a bunch of elements in the key.

But, how would I get only the first 3 elements?

I currently have this (but I think there will be a better way to do it):

```
let firstelement = element.elements[0];
let secondelement = element.elements[1];
let thirdelement = element.elements[2];
```

I'm not sure what to do after this.

Comment: Looks like an array, so `slice`?

Answer (score 4):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

> The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included). The original array will not be modified.

So try this:

```
let element = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('element'));
var selection = element.elements.slice(0, 3);
```

---

Kudos to CertainPerformance for suggesting to use `slice` in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54394216/javascript-local-storage-get-only-first-3-elements/54394229#comment95600080_54394216).

Comment: thanks, that is just elements 2 and 3 right? So your example is 2 elements?

Comment: Correct @user2719875, and great catch! I updated the answer to use the correct indices.

Answer (score 1):

JS has the `slice()` method, which returns a bit-wise copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from `begin` to `end`,`end` will not be included.

**NOTE**: The original array will not be modified.

```js
let txtElement = '{"id":"0001","type":"donut","name":"Cake","elements":[{"id":"5001","type":"None"},{"id":"5002","type":"Glazed"},{"id":"5005","type":"Sugar"},{"id":"5007","type":"Powdered Sugar"},{"id":"5006", "type":"Chocolate with Sprinkles"},{"id":"5003","type":"Chocolate"},{"id":"5004","type":"Maple"}]}';

let localStorage = {
  name: 'Local',
  getItem: function() {
    return txtElement;
  }
};

let element = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('element'));
let topElements = element.elements.slice(0, 3);
console.log({topElements});
```